# Evaluating the line integral $\int \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2}\mathrm dy$ around a circle

Tags: contour-integration, line-integrals

> Evaluate the line integral
>
> $$\int \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2}\mathrm dy$$
>
> Around the circle $x^2+y^2=a^2$ on the positive direction

How to solve this? I don't have an idea. Should I parameterize $x=t$ and then get $y=\sqrt{a^2-t^2}$, find the $\mathrm dt$ and then substituting in the integral?

But what is the bounds? From $0$ to $a$?

Please verify and help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put $x=a\cos \theta, y=a\sin \theta$. the integral becomes $a^{2}\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^{2} \theta \sin^{2} \theta  d\theta$. Can you evaluate this?

Comment: Yes, i do. Thanks for the answer.